# Solutions to the Anticommutator Matrix Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm investigating matrices with regards to antisymmetric properties, and I'm curious if there is a general solution to
$$[A,X]=B$$
in terms of a (constant) matrix $X$, where $[A,X]$ denotes for shorthand the anticommutator $AX+XA$ (note: not $AX-XA$) and $A$ and $B$ are given matrices. For simplicity, let $A$ and $B$ be real symmetric pos. def. matrices. Is there a reference for this if it's true, or is it possibly a deep result requiring much theory and/or more conditions?

Comment: To user76790:  if I am not mistaken, the notations $[Z, W]_+$ and $\{Z, W\}$ are both sometimes used for the anitcommutator $ZW + WZ$; such symbolism avoids possible confusion with the Lie bracket $[Z, W] = ZW - WZ$!

Answer (score 4):

This looks to me like it works:

Since $A$ is real symmetric positive definite, there exists an orthogonal matrix $O$ diagonalizing $A$:

$O^TAO = \Lambda, \tag{1}$

where $\Lambda_{ij} = 0$ for $i \ne j$ and $\Lambda_{ii} = \lambda_i$, where the (real) $\lambda_i > 0$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.  We perform the transformation $Z \to O^TZO$ on the given equation

$AX + XA = B, \tag{2}$

obtaining

$O^T(AX + XA)O = O^TBO, \tag{3}$

which using $OO^T = O^TO = I$ may be written as

$O^TAOO^TXO + O^TXOO^TAO = O^TBO, \tag{4}$

or, with the aid of (1),

$\Lambda O^TXO + O^TXO \Lambda = O^TBO. \tag{5}$

Now, for the sake of notational convenience, let us set $O^TXO = Y$ and $O^TBO = C$; then (5) becomes

$\Lambda Y + Y \Lambda = C. \tag{6}$

We compute $\Lambda Y$ and $Y \Lambda$, setting

$Y = [y_{ij}]; \tag{7}$

an elementary calculation reveals that

$\Lambda Y = [\lambda_i y_{ij}], \tag{8}$

and

$Y \Lambda = [\lambda_j y_{ij}]; \tag{9}$

that is, left multiplication by the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ multiplies the row $i$ of $Y$ by $\lambda_i$; right multiplication by $\Lambda$ multiplies column $j$ of $Y$ by $\lambda_j$.  Combining (6), (8) and (9) we find

$[(\lambda_i + \lambda_j) y_{ij}] = [\lambda_i y_{ij}] + [\lambda_j y_{ij}] = \Lambda Y + Y \Lambda = C. \tag{10}$

(10) may readily be solved for $Y$; indeed we have

$Y = [y_{ij}] = [(\lambda_i + \lambda_j)^{-1}c_{ij}], \tag{11}$

where $C = [c_{ij}]$.  Division by $\lambda_i + \lambda_j$ is always an admissible operation in this context, since all the $\lambda_i > 0$, so that $\lambda_i + \lambda_j > 0$ as well.  Having obtained $Y$ *via* (11), we may re-capture $X$ by performing the inverse of the conjugation $Z \to O^TZO$; thus

$X = OYO^T; \tag{12}$

a complete solution is thus had in the event that $A$ is symmetric positive definite.

In closing, perhaps a few remarks are in order:

**1.)**  The condition that $A$ by symmetric positive definite can be considerably relaxed and the above solution technique will still basically fly.  For example, if we
merely assume $A$ is diagonizable with positive eigenvalues, essentially the same steps apply with the proviso that the orthogonal matrix $O$ is replaced by the matrix $E$ which diagonalizes $A$:

$E^{-1}AE = \Lambda \tag{13}$

in this case, and $E^{-1}$ replaces $O^T$ in the preceding algebraic maneuvers.

**2.)**  We can actually go a step further and allow diagonalizable $A$ to have real eigenvalues of both signs, as long as we insist that $\lambda_i \ne -\lambda_j$ for any two eigenvalues of $A$.

**3.)**  Apparently generalizations into the complex domain are also feasible:  for instance, we may take $A$ to be *Hermitian*, $A^\dagger = A$, so the eigenvalues are real, and insist the criterion posited in (2.) apply: $\lambda_i \ne -\lambda_j$ for all $i, j$; in this case, $O$ would be replaced by some unitary matrix $U$ with $U^\dagger U = U U^\dagger = I$.

**4.)**  Hell's bells, boyz, in for a penny, in for a pound, I always say!  Rather than continue to describe various incremental expansions of the class of feasible $A$,
let's just take $A$ to be an *arbitrary* diagonalizable complex matrix such that the above eigenvalue criterion applies; then it appears that the technique described here applies.

**5.)**  Of course in the above the diagonalizing matrices $O$, $E$, $U$ all have as their columns the eigenvectors of $A$.

**6.)**  When $A$ can't be diagonalized it can be reduced to a set of Jordan blocks, at least one of which will be of the form $\lambda I + N$ where $N$ is the usual nilpotent matrix.  Not sure what happens in this case, but it would be interesting to pursue the analogous argument and see what happens.

**7.)**  Apparently there is no restriction needs be placed on $B$ other than its existence;)!

Finally,

**8.)**  A related, similar method can be attempted for equations of the form $AX - XA = B$; then one obtains the analogous condition that $\lambda_i - \lambda_j \ne 0$ for all $i, j, i \ne j$; apparently, since $\lambda_i - \lambda_i = 0$, we would have to have $c_{ii} = 0$, all $i$, and the $y_{ii}$ are unconstrained.  ***NB:  Not really sure how this works out!  But in a Lie algebra, anything is possible!***  I would love to do more with this situation but have neither the time nor the space (here) at present to do so . . . takers, anyone?

OK, I'm typed out for the moment at least.  My name's Bob; thanks for letting me share:)

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ has a full set of eigenvectors, the answer is straightforward:

Expand the linear operator $L(X) = AX+XA$ in terms of the basis $u_i v_j^*$ (where $u_k$ are the eigenvectors of $A$, $v_k$ are the eigenvectors of $A^*$). $L$ is diagonal in this basis, and the diagonal elements are $\lambda_i + \lambda_j $. (A condition for invertibility falls out from this.)

Answer (score 1):

Much more generally, let $L:X\rightarrow AX+XB$ where $A,B\in\mathcal{M}_n(K)$ with $K$ an algebraically closed field. Let $spectrum(A)=(\lambda_i)_i,spectrum(B)=(\mu_j)_j$. Then $spectrum(L)=(\lambda_i+\mu_j)_{i,j}$ (without any hypothesis on $A,B$; in particular, $A,B$ do not need to be diagonalizable !)

Proof: In fact $L$ is the sum of two Kronecker products $L=A\otimes I+I\otimes B^T$. cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product
Moreover $A\otimes I$ and $I\otimes B^T$ are $n^2\times n^2$ matrices that commute (because $(AX)B=A(XB)$) and, consequently, they are simultaneously triangularizable. The eigenvalues of $A\otimes I$ are $(\lambda_i)_i$, each $n$ times, and the eigenvalues of $I\otimes B^T$ are $(\mu_i)_i$, each $n$ times. It is not difficult to see, considering the triangular forms of $A\otimes I$ and $I\otimes B^T$, that we obtain the $(\lambda_i+\mu_j)_{i,j}$ on the diagonal of the sum.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what mistake I made please? Not stating a result in its greatest generality is not a mistake. The goal is to help the OP.

Comment: @copper.hat, the correct basis is composed with the $(u_i\otimes u_j)_{i,j}$. In fact, there is a linear isomorphism linking the $(u_i\otimes u_j)_{i,j}$ and the $(u_ivj^T)_{i,j}$ and not the $(u_ivj^*)_{i,j}$ ! Finally, the lines of your proof are correct if you change the symbol $^*$ with the symbol $^T$. Moreover, your calculation is not a generalization; indeed you study the application $X\rightarrow AX+X\overline{A}$.

Comment: What or who is the OP ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what mistake I made in the above referenced answer? OP means 'original poster'. My answer below is & was correct, albeit accidentally, because $A$ is real & symmetric. Also, the convention is to point out presumed mistakes in a comment to the relevant answer; that way the answerer gets notified and can make amends if they so wish.

Comment: @copper.hat, is it a joke ? As you wrote, your reasoning was false but the result was accidentally right. If you were happy with your post why did you edit it 9 hours ago ?

Comment: Gosh, you really need to work on your social sklls. My reasoning was fine, but I made a mistake in both answers by omitting a $ ^*$. In the above case, the answer was still correct since $A$ is real and symmetric, but misleading since I had the unnecessary conjugation. I edited to fix it, of course, prompted by your correct observation.

Comment: @copper.g=hat, Ok. If it makes you happy, I remove my remark above.