# Decomposition of a bounded Hilbert space operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to prove the following homework problem:
Let $B$ be a positive operator on a Hilbert space $H$ with $\Vert B\Vert=1$ and $B$ is invertible. Try to prove that for each $\,T\in \mathfrak{B}(H,H)$, there exists an $S\in\mathfrak B(H,H)\,$ such that $\,T=\frac{1}{2}(BS+SB)\,$.

I have tried to apply the polar decomposition of $T$ but seemingly in vain. Actually, I am wondering how the condition $\Vert B\Vert=1$ is used.

Can somebody give me some hints on this problem?

Comment: I don't think the norm bound is relevant. The claim to be proven is invariant under scaling of B.

Comment: You are right, so it seems that we only need to assume that $B$ is a bounded operator.

Comment: Using a result on the spectrum of inner automorphisms of Banach algebras (see Bonsall F.F., Duncan J.: Complete Normed Algebras, p.88, Proposition 9(ii))  it follows that the spectrum of $S \mapsto B^{-1}SB$  is a subset of $\{\mu/\lambda: \mu,\lambda \in \sigma(B)\} \subseteq (0,\infty)$. Hence $S \mapsto S +B^{-1}SB$ is invertible in the algebra of bounded operators on ${\cal B}(H,H)$.

Comment: The case of finite dimension, [solution to $AX+XA =B$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/528831/580448)

Answer (score 4):

Let us begin within a more general setting. Fix an $\,A\in\mathfrak B=\mathfrak B(H,H)$,
and define the *Lyapunov operator*
$$L:\mathfrak B\to\mathfrak B,\quad X\mapsto A^*X+XA$$
(which is a special case of the Sylvester operator).

An operator $A\in\mathfrak B\,$ is said to be *stable* if its spectrum is contained in the open left half-plane of $\,\mathbb C$.
An $A\in\mathfrak B\,$ is said to be *positively stable*, if $-A\,$ is stable, i. e., each spectral value of $A$ has a strictly positive real part.
In particular, $A^*$ is positively stable iff $A$ is positively stable.

For a positively stable $A$ the expressions $\,\exp(-tA^*)\,$ and $\,\exp(-tA)\,$
where $0\leqslant t< \infty\,$ define norm-continuous one-parameter semigroups tending to zero for large $t$. They allow for each $X\in\mathfrak B\,$ to define the nicely convergent integral
$$S(X)\:=\:\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-tA^*}X\,e^{-tA}\,dt\,,$$
which is an explicit inverse of the Lyapunov operator.
Checking this involves the product rule for differentiation with respect to $t\,$:
$$L\big(S(X)\big)=A^*S(X)+S(X)A
=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-tA^*}
(A^*X+XA)\:e^{-tA}\,dt}_{\qquad\quad=\,S(L(X))}
=-\int\limits_0^\infty \frac d{dt}\big(e^{-tA^*}X
\:e^{-tA}\big)dt = X$$
If $B\in\mathfrak B$ is a positive operator $($then $B^*=B\,)$ and invertible, then $\frac12 B\,$ is strictly positive, hence positively stable. It follows from the preceding that for each $T\in\mathfrak B$ there is a Lyapunov preimage $S\in\mathfrak B$, i.e.,
$\,L(S)=\frac12(BS+SB)\,=T$, and $\,S\,$ is unique.

Comment: Thanks! How did you get the uniqueness at the very end (which is not needed to answer the question)? From what you showed, it only follows that your integral expression is a right inverse of the Ljapunov operator, which gives you existence, but not uniqueness. [I will award the bounty to you in any case]

Comment: Thank you @PhoemueX for the bounty $-$ very appreciated! I shall edit the answer to respond to your comment, including that $S(T)$ is also a left inverse.